# *** -[__NSArrayM release]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, xcode4, nsarray, uipagecontrol

I am developing a app similar to `PageControl` sample provided by Apple.
My app fetch data from server and store it in an `NSMutableArray` locally.
Then display that array in grid format by loading cell **nib**.

My app runs on simulator with some lag during wipe but when I try to run it on device my app crashes.

Also when I run it on device using `Instruments` it executes fine.

Have enabled zombies and get following error.

```
*** -[__NSArrayM release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x18aef0
```

This is what I am doing:

1. On `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I call two webservices, fetch data
   and store it in local array
2. Push the view controller where pages are generated

Trying to resolve same.

---

Here is my code.

```
    //**AppDelegate.h**
    @interface TumBhiAppDelegate : UIResponder  {
    NSMutableArray *arrDetailsByCategory;
    }
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSMutableArray *arrDetailsByCategory;    
    -(IBAction)doneProcessing:(id)sender;
    @end

    //**AppDelegate.m**
    #import "AppDelegate.h"
    #import "Server.h"

    @implementation AppDelegate
    @synthesize arrDetailsByCategory;
    //Once processing is done push the view
    -(IBAction)doneProcessing:(id)sender
    {    
    BaseContentViewController *baseController = [[BaseContentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BaseContentViewController" bundle:nil];    
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:baseController animated:YES];    
    [baseController release];
    }

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
    arrDetailsByCategory  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[TumBhiViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TumBhiViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    //getDetails is called 5-6 time
    //arrDetailsByCategory is populated accordingly 
    [Server getDetails:@"ABC"];
    [self doneProcessing:nil];
    return YES;
    }
    @end

    //**Server.h**
    @interface ServerCommunication : NSObject{
    }
    -(BOOL)getDetails:(NSString *)str
    @end

    //**Server.m**
    #import "Server.h"
    #import "AppDelegate.h"
    @implementation ServerCommunication

    -(BOOL)getDetails:(NSString *)str
    {
    NSMutableArray *arrFinal = [NSMutableArray array];
    //call web-service populate arrFinal
    [[[AppDelegate GetAppDelegate] arrDetailsByCategory] addObjectsFromArray:arrFinal];
    }
   @end
```

**Debugger Message**

```
*** -[__NSArrayM release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7aa0870
[Switching to process 636 thread 0x15903]
[Switching to process 636 thread 0x15903]
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
(gdb)
```

**Stack message:**

```
0x01920db0  <+0096>  testb  $0x1,(%eax)
0x01920db3  <+0099>  je     0x1920ded <___forwarding___+157>
0x01920db5  <+0101>  mov    %edi,0x4(%esp)
0x01920db9  <+0105>  movl   $0x0,0x18(%esp)
0x01920dc1  <+0113>  movl   $0x0,0x14(%esp)
0x01920dc9  <+0121>  movl   $0x0,0x10(%esp)
0x01920dd1  <+0129>  movl   $0x0,0xc(%esp)
0x01920dd9  <+0137>  movl   $0x0,0x8(%esp)
0x01920de1  <+0145>  movl   $0x15,(%esp)
0x01920de8  <+0152>  call   0x198ec10 <__CFRecordAllocationEvent>
0x01920ded  <+0157>  mov    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
0x01920df0  <+0160>  mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x01920df3  <+0163>  call   0x19fcbf6 <dyld_stub_sel_getName>
0x01920df8  <+0168>  mov    %edi,0x10(%esp)
0x01920dfc  <+0172>  mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
0x01920e00  <+0176>  add    $0xa,%esi
0x01920e03  <+0179>  mov    %esi,0x8(%esp)
0x01920e07  <+0183>  lea    0x12e6aa(%ebx),%eax
0x01920e0d  <+0189>  mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x01920e11  <+0193>  movl   $0x3,(%esp)
0x01920e18  <+0200>  call   0x196bad0 <CFLog>
0x01920e1d  <+0205>  int3   
0x01920e1e  <+0206>  call   0x19fc8b4 <dyld_stub_getpid> //**Dies here with Thread 5**
0x01920e23  <+0211>  mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x01920e26  <+0214>  movl   $0x9,0x4(%esp)
0x01920e2e  <+0222>  call   0x19fc908 <dyld_stub_kill>
0x01920e33  <+0227>  xor    %edi,%edi
0x01920e35  <+0229>  jmp    0x192112e <___forwarding___+990>
0x01920e3a  <+0234>  lea    0xed29f(%ebx),%eax
0x01920e40  <+0240>  mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x01920e44  <+0244>  mov    %esi,(%esp)
0x01920e47  <+0247>  call   0x19fcc56 <dyld_stub_strcmp>
0x01920e4c  <+0252>  test   %eax,%eax
0x01920e4e  <+0254>  mov    %edi,%eax
0x01920e50  <+0256>  mov    %eax,%edi
0x01920e52  <+0258>  mov    %eax,-0x14(%ebp)
0x01920e55  <+0261>  jne    0x1920e63 <___forwarding___+275>
0x01920e57  <+0263>  mov    0x130e5a(%ebx),%eax
0x01920e5d  <+0269>  mov    -0x14(%ebp),%ecx
0x01920e60  <+0272>  mov    (%ecx,%eax,1),%edi
0x01920e63  <+0275>  mov    %edi,(%esp)
0x01920e66  <+0278>  call   0x19fcad6 <dyld_stub_object_getClass>
0x01920e6b  <+0283>  mov    0x1255ee(%ebx),%ecx
```

Comment: show your code, without it we can't help you

Comment: Also give us a stack trace please.

Comment: Provided with stack trace and debugger message. Thank you.

Comment: The error code keeps on changing. I executed it today and got error in debugger as: *** -[__NSArrayM release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7ab64f0

Answer (score -5):

May be Your data array could get deallocated by means of any logical error before release message is sent to it

Use break points to check where it was get deallocated

Comment: NEVER send dealloc to something that is not `super`